# Facebook Notification - What is the code parameter on the URL

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an Mobile App that is integrated with Facebook. So far I've only developed the Android version. The app sends notifications to users so they can confirm their presence on soccer matches.

When a user clicks on the notification using a desktop version of the facebook everything goes fine, the facebook canvas page sends a post request with a signed_request. But on the iOS version, since I don't have the app yet, the user is redirected to the following url:

[my canvas web url]?ref=notif&code=AQD6fUp8oAvz9pDD1ygEfoaXW6ls3jEyhPsBmZP-nXrhQw67U0BBqZXJPa6MDyJu1_kSuUYjFPP-RtGRvdv7iyADlJavuZqqDsnNF7AAfDSatopNQEeBqplEUhhDXVDZcUSBFjZFcEmhwdboPliFE5jbjk4PyJY1_vOaE4b4UAbs11pOJXGRq2RU_mJUC2GPzBT63W-aewc60bHTiXrMzgzI_Da3Sp0mlAa7SQn1rF-co2Au-BDDGpV694bOmC5PtJBpIJTU_FO_bwl-vb3bDeQOp-XRLe8_K3JP3hQhutcFy7jeSySP0D2dhVDPgwUn9u8&fb_source=notification&request_ids=196632097193420&app_request_type=user_to_user#_=

I don't know how to parse this url, and it doesn't have a signed request. I've googled a little bit and found out that this code querystring parameter can be used to get an access token (when building login), but I need a redirect_uri. I don't know what I can do with this URL to get what user this is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you saw the [official](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial/#requests) article about it? It has a parity good explanations there. I don't see it as a bad experience at all.

Comment: Yes, maybe I'm not looking it right but I can't find the part where it says how to handle app requests when you don't have a native app :(

Comment: @Thiago In Facebook dashboard, when you define your native IOS app, users who don't have ios native app will be redirected to download it(if they are getting the notification in ios of course).

Comment: I think that's the point you're not getting. I don't have my IOS app defined on the dashboard. I only have Android, Website and Canvas. But I'm still getting notifications on iOS and being redirected to that URL that I posted about. I wanna know how to get the user from that url.

Comment: @Thiago Now I got you. Look at the request ids. Your canvas application should be able to handle it. It supose to be the same as canvas user.

Comment: I couldn't find where to get information from the request id. Maybe I have to save it on my database right?