# Facebook App - How to not link requests to native app

Tags: android, ios, facebook, mobile

I'm building an app that will let users organize soccer matches and invite their friends on facebook.

On the experience I want to bring, only the person organizing needs to have the app installed. I want him to be able to send requests to his friends, and whenever they click on it, they will be redirected to a simple webpage so they can confirm their presence or not. That means that I don't want to make the "players" of the match have the app installed, but I want them to be able to confirm their presences through mobile phones.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to implement it using Facebook SDK than you can't. All the Facebook api action such as sending requests or handling incoming request requires valid taken, so the user must have the app installed on web or mobile.

Your only option is notify the users using other methods, such as email, sms, or even a phone call that your application will make.

How ever I do not suggest you any of those. Use Facebook, let all your users to install your app, do it the Facebook way.

**Edit**: Also see [Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/android-tutorial/#requests) and [ios](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/mobile/ios-tutorial/#requests) requests in Facebook.

Comment: is there any way for the user to be able to use my facebook app (installing it) on, let's say, iOS, before I implement the native app? A sort of mobile canvas app.

Comment: @Thiago Don't be afraid to start with 50% of the final app, you can always update it, and add more futures to it.

Comment: The thing is that my value proposition is easiness for the players to confirm their presence. We have another tool like the one I'm building, in Brazil, but it's a terrible experience for the user to go and confirm their presence on the match. Do you know any workaround this? My users do receive a notification on iOS but when they click they go to a url that I don't know what to do. As you can see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20777880/facebook-notification-what-is-the-code-parameter-on-the-url).

Comment: @Thiago I added link that might help you